# Storing Files on File Server or in Data Base?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-word

I'm developing some web app in ASP.Net which is mainly about Storing, Sharing and Processing MS Word doc and PDF files, but I'm not sure how to manage these documents, I was thinking of keeping documents in folders and only keeping metadata of them in DB OR keeping the whole documents in DB,I'm using SQL Server 2008. what's your suggestion?

Comment: Depends on you needs, if you looking for speed I would use folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 is reasonably good at storing and serving up large documents (unlike some of the earlier versions), so it is definitely an option.  That said, having large blobs being served up from the DB is generally not a great idea.  I think you need to think about the advantages and disadvantages of both approaches.  Some general things to think about:

- How large are the files going to be, and how many of them will there be?  It's a lot easier to scale a file system past many TB than it is to do the same for a DB.
- How do you want to manage backups?  Obviously with a file system approach you'd need to back the files up separately from the DB.

I believe it's probably quicker to implement a solution that stores to the DB, but that storing to the file system is generally the superior solution.  In the latter case, however, you will have to worry about some issues, such as having unique file names, and in general not wanting to store too many documents in a single folder (most solutions create new folders after every few thousand documents).  Use the quicker approach if the files are not going to be numerous and large, otherwise invest some time in storing on the file system.

Answer (score 3):

In the database unless you **don't care** about data integrity.

If you store docs outside of the database you **will** have missing documents and broken links soomer not later. Your backup/restore scenario is a lot more complex: you have no way to ensure that all data is from the same point in time.

FILESTREAM in SQL Server 2008 makes it efficient nowadays (and other RDBMS have features like this too)

Answer (score 0):

If your storing these files in one folder, then maintain the files names in the DB. Since no dir can have 2 files names same with same extension. If you wish to store the file into DB, then you may have to use BLOB or byte array to store.

I see over head in opening a connection to the DB, though i dont know how fast the DB connection is compared to file.Open (even peformance wise).

Answer (score 0):

If files are relatively small I would store them as BLOB fields in database. This way you can use standard procedures for backup/restore as well as transactions. If files are large there are some advantages in keeping them on the hard drive and storing filenames in the database as was suggested earlier

Answer (score 0):

If you are going *only* operate on that files I would think to store them i **DB** like a `BLOB` data. In case if you have a files on folders and only names in DB, you should care about the fact that, for example:

1) one day you may need rename file

2) change its location

3) change its extension

or whatever.

In case of **DB** instead, you can save in separate table `BLOB` data, in other table *name* and *extension* of the file along with its *ID* on `BLOB` table. In this case, in moment of previously discussed scenario you will need just execute simple **SQL** update query.

Answer (score 0):

How many documents are you planning to store?

The main advantage of the database approach is the normal [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) properties--the meta-data will always be consistent with the document, which will not be the case if you use the file system to store the documents. Using the file system it would be relatively easy for your meta-data and documents to get out of sync: documents on the file system for which there is no meta-data, meta-data where the document has gone missing or is corrupted. If you need any sort of reliability in your document storage, then the database is a much better approach than using the file system.